# Operations to empty rows below the last non empty row

Tags: r

I have a panel data structure with 32 IDs and observations from 1980 to 1989. It looks like this (only with id 1 and 2)

```r
dput(data)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), year = c(1980, 1980, 
1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 1986, 
1986, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989), d = c(0.60217061447157, 
0.245678224008021, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need the column "d" to increase over time for each id by adding 1 unit to the previous value.

I am struggling to find a way to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can group by the `id`s and add the `row_number()`

```r
library(dplyr)
# you can replace `d[1]` with `first(d)`
data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(d=d[1]+row_number()-1)
# or by adding year - 1980
data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(d=d[1]+year-1980)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
      id  year     d
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  1980 0.602
 2     2  1980 0.246
 3     1  1981 1.60 
 4     2  1981 1.25 
 5     1  1982 2.60 
 6     2  1982 2.25 
 7     1  1983 3.60 
 8     2  1983 3.25 
 9     1  1984 4.60 
10     2  1984 4.25 
11     1  1985 5.60 
12     2  1985 5.25 
13     1  1986 6.60 
14     2  1986 6.25 
15     1  1987 7.60 
16     2  1987 7.25 
17     1  1988 8.60 
18     2  1988 8.25 
19     1  1989 9.60 
20     2  1989 9.25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library('data.table')
# order by year and group by id. 
setDT(dt)[order(year), .(year,
                         d = d[1]+seq(0, .N-1)),
          by = .(id)]
#     id year         d
#  1:  1 1980 0.6021706
#  2:  1 1981 1.6021706
#  3:  1 1982 2.6021706
#  4:  1 1983 3.6021706
#  5:  1 1984 4.6021706
#  6:  1 1985 5.6021706
#  7:  1 1986 6.6021706
#  8:  1 1987 7.6021706
#  9:  1 1988 8.6021706
# 10:  1 1989 9.6021706
# 11:  2 1980 0.2456782
# 12:  2 1981 1.2456782
# 13:  2 1982 2.2456782
# 14:  2 1983 3.2456782
# 15:  2 1984 4.2456782
# 16:  2 1985 5.2456782
# 17:  2 1986 6.2456782
# 18:  2 1987 7.2456782
# 19:  2 1988 8.2456782
# 20:  2 1989 9.2456782
```

**Data:**

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
                     year = c(1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989), 
                     d = c(0.60217061447157, 0.245678224008021, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, d := first(d) + seq_len(.N) - 1, id]
```